# debug a bug in c++ code or eclipse

Tags: c++

i have this code but eclipse release error on return line but i know that int array[][] is same type by int **

```
int ** Master::what_can_choose()
{
array_can_choose[9][2]={0};
board[3][3]={{' ',' ','x'},{' ','o',' '},{'x',' ',' '}};
int x=0;
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
    if (board[i][j]==' ')
        {
        array_can_choose[x][0]=i;
        array_can_choose[x][1]=i;
        x+=1;
        }
    }
}
return array_can_choose;
}
```

why this error is released

```
error is: cannot convert `int (*)[2]' to `int**' in return
```

Comment: What's the error? Which line? What do you mean with the types?

Comment: error is cannot convert `int (*)[2]' to `int**' in return

Comment: @user2059070 it's because the types aren't compatible …

Comment: What you wanted to say in your question (`int[][]` == `int**`) is simply **not true**. Why don't you use container classes like `std::vector`?

Comment: why both of them is pointer to pointer

Comment: Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not array. Accept that and you'll save yourself a lot of hassle.

Comment: Try `return &array_can_choose[0]` Yes, @leemes.

Comment: First, no, an array is not simply a pointer. [Read about that in a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Secondly, please don't use raw arrays in C++. Use `std::vector` for dynamic and `std::array` for constant (compile-time known) sized collections.

Comment: @AshRj This is an `int *` You mean `&array_can_choose[0]`. I'm not sure if this even solves the problem, since I seldom hack with raw arrays.

Comment: @AshRj tankyou but dont solved

Comment: You should never return a pointer to a local non-static variable.

Comment: @leemes tankyou dont solved by &array_can_choose[0]

Comment: @leemes It should solve the problem. I have used this on array pointers before, just not on double pointers.

Comment: Whats the error message now ?

Comment: cannot convert `int (*)[2]' to `int**'

Comment: @molbdnilo please explain-i check it but it realse error too

Comment: @user2059070 [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) is the "canonical" question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, an `int**` is not the same as an `int[][]`. If you're using an `int**` as a 2D-array with dynamic allocation, the internal structure is actually very different from a real 2D-array. Take a look at this code:

```
int** dynamic2DArray;
int static2DArray[10][10];

dynamic2DArray = new int*[10];
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
    dynamic2DArray[i] = new int[10];
```

Now, `dynamic2DArray` points to the first element in a list of 10 pointers which each point to a list of 10 `int`s, while `static2DArray` points to the first element in a list of 10*10=100 `int`s. So the structure in memory is completely different.

In addition, the following would also be a `int**`, while clearly having nothing to do with arrays:

```
int someInt;
int* pointerToSomeInt = &someInt;
int** doublePointerToSomeInt = &pointerToSomeInt;
```

A syntax error I spotted is that you're not declaring what type your arrays should be:

```
array_can_choose[9][2]={0};
board[3][3]={{' ',' ','x'},{' ','o',' '},{'x',' ',' '}};
```

Should be:

```
int array_can_choose[9][2]={0};
char board[3][3]={{' ',' ','x'},{' ','o',' '},{'x',' ',' '}};
```

This is because we don't just need to tell the compiler that we want an array, but also what it should be an array of. In this case, `int` and `char`.

Another problem with your code is that you're trying to return a local array. You can't do this. A local variable exists only so long as 'its name is known' (this is called  'being in scope'). In this case, the variable `array_can_choose` will cease to exist as soon as you exit from the function `int ** Master::what_can_choose()`.

You may wonder why you can then ever return a variable from a function at all. This is because most variables can be copied. This is what happens when you return (for example) an `int` from a function, or when you pass an `int` into a function. However, arrays cannot be copied. This has been done to prevent immense unexpected slow-downs when copying very large arrays. Instead, when you pass an array into a function, you're only passing a variable which points to the contents of the array. This means that you cannot return a local array because the contents of this array will cease to exist when exiting the function. Therefor the return variable would point to 'not-existing' memory.

To circumvent this, you would have to use dynamic allocation:

```
int ** Master::what_can_choose()
{
    //dynamically allocate the array we want to return
    int** array_can_choose = new int*[9];
    for( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
    {
        array_can_choose[i] = new int[2];
        for( int j=0; j<2; j++ )
            array_can_choose[i][j] = 0; //initialize all values to 0
    }

    //a type (such as char) is required for arrays
    char board[3][3]={{' ',' ','x'},{' ','o',' '},{'x',' ',' '}};
    int x=0;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j]==' ')
            {
                array_can_choose[x][0]=i;
                array_can_choose[x][1]=i;
                x+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return array_can_choose;
}
```

Now, one drawback of using dynamic allocation is that you will also have to free the memory you allocated. Dynamic allocation ensures that memory will exist even when you leave the current scope (that's why we can now return our array), but this means it is no longer clear when the memory is allowed to '*stop* existing'. Because of this, we explicitly need to tell the compiler when we're done with our memory, so that it can then free this memory. We can do this using `delete[]`. The `[]`-part tells the compiler it should delete an entire array, not just one item. Because we allocated an array of arrays, we can't just do this deletion at once. We have to delete every sub-array and then the 2D-array itself (which, as explained before, is really a 1D-array of pointers to arrays).

```
Master master; //we need an object to call our function
int** our_array = master.what_can_choose(); //this allocates an array and stores it in our_array

//do stuff with our_array

for( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
    delete[] our_array[i]; //delete a sub-array
delete[] our_array; //delete the array itself.

//we can now no longer do stuff with our_array
```

Not deleting memory like this means that the memory we allocated will forever be occupied even if we don't need it any more, this is called a '*memory leak*'. If you do this too often, your computer will eventually run out of memory and your program will crash.

Comment: ok  ok tanckyou very much

Comment: my  Reputation is 14 i new user if it vope up to 15 i will vope up you

Comment: i vope up it very tankyou